# How to pass NSURL to view controller from delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So my application opens a file format. Since the app is running it uses applicationWillEnterForeground to call application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:. Once I have my NSURL in my delegate my previous view opens and I have done anything with the NSURL.

My app of course is using a storyboard so I just can't call the XIB like most tutorials have you do.  So my question how do I get that file to view controller to open and progress it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create property in your AppDelegate.h file to hold the NSURL:

```
@property (nonatomic, string) NSURL *myURL;
```

And in

> application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

save the url to new property:

```
self.myUrl = url;
```

After that you can access the url from every single view controller in your app.
Passing url from delegate is not good solution because when the

> application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

is called your view controller can be nil.

Comment: how does the app know when to check that string if the view is already running?

Comment: Read the myURL property in viewDidAppeare:animated, this method is called after applicationWillEnterForeground. Check it is it null for safety issues.